# How to optimize 'string.split("&").sort.join("&")' using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and in my code I have this:

```
string = "surname=testsurname&name=testname"
string.split("&").sort.join("&")

# Now the 'string' value is "name=testname&surname=testsurname"
```

**There is a better way to do that?**

Comment: That looks ok to me, but what are you doing with this?  It looks like a request query string.

Comment: Better how?  I doubt you'll find anything considerably faster or more concise than the code you listed...

Comment: I really hope you're not parsing URI parameters with that.

Comment: I am trying to "canonicalize" a string request. So?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by better you mean faster, then probably not. That's a fairly straightforward implementation of what you're intending to do. How often are you calling this method? What context is it being called in? To optimize this you would probably look at ways to avoid performing this operation more times than is strictly required.

Answer (score 0):

```
for better understanding you can change your code a little bit

string = "surname = testsurname & name = testname".split(" & ").sort().join(" & ")

=> "name = testname & surname = testsurname"
```